# Why isn't the FAQ Index presented Jeopardy-style?

Tags: discussion, meta-faq

On askubuntu.com, we're starting an [Intro to Ubuntu FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38156/).  I modeled it almost exactly like the [FAQ for SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931), but as one user pointed out, this doesn't follow the ["Jeopardy-style" question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq) rule.  Is there any particular reason the Stack Exchange FAQ is structured differently than the FAQ page stipulates?

Comment: Might want to clarify the usage of the two FAQs you are talking about: the URL **[/faq](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq)** and the [index of faq-tagged questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931).  It had me majorly stumped the first time I read this question.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, notice how each individual question linked to by the FAQ for SE Sites is actually posted as such - they ask a question and the answer provides the, well, answer.

The "landing" post, then, is primarily a host to links to all of these. Each link corresponds to one question, which means that they all fit within the question body rather than as an answer. The question isn't, after all, "What are all the frequently asked questions?"

---

Perhaps more importantly, it's *more practical* to organize the FAQ in this fashion. This keeps all of the links at the very top, so anyone who knows where to find it can just click on the link and immediately find themselves at the collection of links. It also prevents the collection of links from being subject to sort order and voting.

While asking questions is definitely a preferable course, the main goal of the Meta site is to be a support place. It may be on a Q&A platform, but we can afford some leeway if it can mean some proper convenience. The large FAQ just isn't a question at all, so there's not as much need to treat it like one. It's basically meant to be a hub for all of the actual questions - an easier form of navigation than using [faq](/questions/tagged/faq).

Comment: Just to add to this: originally, it *was* jeopardy-style - the questions were in the question, the answers were in answers. It worked pretty well, until it got too big.